# solr date facet 'end' is not a valid Date string

Tags: solr, facet

I have a request where i used face.date, but when i try to set day+1 to 'end' i have that error :

```
 date facet 'end' is not a valid Date string: NOW/DAY/+1DAYS
```

See my request :

```
$URL_requeteSolr = $O_solr->test().'&q='.$S_a.$S_b.'&rows=10000&facet=true&facet.date=d&facet.date.start=NOW/DAY-90DAYS&facet.date.end=NOW/DAY/%2B1DAYS&facet.date.gap=%2B7DAY&wt=json';
```

The problem is "NOW/DAY/%2B1DAYS", if i replace this by 'NOW/DAY'that work.
And i don't understand why that dosn't work, i read many doc and it is like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the start of the next day, `NOW+1DAY/DAY` should do that. The `/` rounds the value in front of it, so `/+1DAY` doesn't make any sense by itself, as the goal of `+1DAY` is to move the point of time a day ahead, not round the previous value.

`NOW/DAY+1DAY` might also work, but I'm unsure of priority when evaluating date math.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer but i have also an erro with facet.date.end=NOW+1DAY/DAY or with facet.date.end=NOW/DAY+1DAY.
I have this error : date facet 'end' is not a valid Date string: NOW/DAY 1DAY
The '+' is not understand

Comment: Have you encoded the `+` in your URL? Remember that `+` is a placeholder for " " in URLs. Try using `%2B` instead, which is the encoded form of `+`

Comment: its ok, the problem was "/", its facet.date.end=NOW/DAY%2B1DAYS and that work nice :)